# How can I choose my ajax response content type dynamically?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

For some reasons, I need choose my response `content-type` by the client request. I'm wondering how can I implement the dynamic request which can manage it. I need something like this:

```
e.g. /api/xml/values or /api/json/values
```

or even:

```
e.g. /api/values?type=xml or /api/values?type=json
```

It's possible to config the `ASP.net Web API` to handle content type dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ASP.NET Web API`, a media-type formatter is an object that can:

- Read CLR objects from an HTTP message body
- Write CLR objects into an HTTP message body

> Web API provides media-type formatters for both `JSON` and `XML`. The
>   framework inserts these formatters into the pipeline by default.
>   Clients can request either JSON or XML in the Accept header of the
>   HTTP request.

So you don't need to change or to set any configuration to achieve that. if you want to determine response content type, you need send proper headers to the server.

e.g. this section provides the `JSON`:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {          
            Accept: "text/json; charset=utf-8",         
            "Content-Type": "text/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        url: '/api/Values',
        method: 'get'
    }).then(console.log);
```

and e.g. this section provides the `XML`:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {          
            Accept: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",         
            "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        },
        url: '/api/Values',
        method: 'get'
    }).then(console.log);
```

## The Results

for first code(JSON content-type):

```
["value1","value2"]
```

and for the second one(XML content-type):

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><string>value1</string><string>value2</string></ArrayOfstring>
```